# Webpack hash the same for css and js files. Both change when only one should

Tags: webpack, survivejs

I'm trying to implement long-term caching of my js project. I've been using the survivejs (http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/developing_with_webpack/) page as a tutorial.

What I've found is that both .css and .js use the same hash:

```
app.860846ea86c7b67eddd0.js       132 kB       0  [emitted]  app
styles.860846ea86c7b67eddd0.css   21 bytes       0  [emitted]  app
```

and when I JUST change .css file, both files are updated (I would expect the .js file to stay the same?).

```
app.353477b32cc15ea06465.js     132 kB       0  [emitted]  app
styles.353477b32cc15ea06465.css   20 bytes       0  [emitted]  app
```

I've verified that the file that wasn't supposed to change has the same md5 sum.

Ultimately what I want is that if I change styling, the generated css hash would change and the js hash would remain the same (and vice-versa). i.e. the js contents hasn't changed, it's cached in the browser, so why force a re-download.

I've created a sample github repo to demonstrate. (The readme has a few more details).

https://github.com/vlod/webpack_chunk_strange/tree/master

I would appreciate some help. I'm fairly new to webpack and it's most likely a config error, but I've spent 2 days trying everything I can.

Thanks.

Comment: node -v => v4.1.0 webpack => 1.12.2

Comment: Author here. I see your repository isn't available anymore. Do you want to push it out there again so I can have a proper look?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've uploaded the repo again to github (the above link should work). Since I couldn't figure out what was wrong (I tried to explain my thinking in the README) and moved to 'webpack-md5-hash' which works. I would still appreciate if you can take a quick look and see if I'm doing anything stupid.

Comment: Alright. I can see one thing straight away. Your configuration doesn't generate a manifest. That's something the chapter was missing earlier. Extracting that manifest portion fixed the hashing behavior. I'll write more about that in an answer.

Comment: Btw, if you have any problems with the book content, feel free to contact me directly in the future. Faster to resolve. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original configuration was that JS/CSS belonged to the same chunk. So if CSS changed, so did the chunk -> both JS/CSS were invalidated. Based on this realization I ended up separating the CSS to a chunk of its own. This can be achieved by setting up an entry point of its own like this:

```
entry: {
  ...
  style: [
    'purecss',
    'highlight.js/styles/github.css',
    'react-ghfork/gh-fork-ribbon.ie.css',
    'react-ghfork/gh-fork-ribbon.css',
    './demo/main.css',
    './style.css'
  ]
}
```

This `entry` pulls all the CSS you need. There are some caveats:

- In addition to CSS, this will generate a JS file. The file won't do much given you most likely just extract the CSS out of it through `ExtractTextPlugin`, but it will still exist.
- The approach won't scale to more complicated scenarios. If you need to refer to CSS from your JS code, you hit the original problem again.

See my [boilerplate](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate) for the full configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually no. I added your suggestion to my project (github project above) and it still exhibits the same problems as before.

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a change to go through the book again to see if you've added anything different to what I've done.

Comment: No worries. You can find [the full source of the book](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack_react). I also have a [boilerplate](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate) with the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the boilerplate link. I've tried using that instead and am getting the same result. I'm probably doing something stupid. Doing a 'npm run gh-pages' on your boilerplate I'm getting app.js and styles.css being generated with hash 'd44713f98d49c51ef8fc'. I then change main.css background from #fefefe to #ff0000 and rerun 'npm run gh-pages'. Both app.js and styles.css have the same hash 'ec64b850f0e97947d7dd' while I would only expect the styles.css to have changed.

Comment: Ok, my bad then. I'll try to get this fixed soon. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Quick update. I tried it with [NamedModulesPlugin](https://github.com/survivejs/react-component-boilerplate/tree/named_modules). The problem is that there's some glitch with that and **ExtractTextPlugin** so the JavaScript portion won't load (it still tried to point at CSS). That's something I need to resolve next.

Comment: @wkalicun I figured out a workaround. The problem was that altering the CSS invalidated the chunk. I ended up setting up a separate entry point for the CSS. This seems to work with some caveats discussed at the answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No probs. I would love to find a proper solution for this. The thread discussing the issue at GitHub is kind of long. :)

Going through a separate chunk seems like the sanest option for now.